# Do I need to mint all ERC721 tokens on the deployment of the smart contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle

beginner in solidity here.

I'm starting to build a trading card game on the Ethereum network using ERC721 tokens because cards will have different stats so I need them to be non-fungible.

My initial plan was to release 10 cards, and later on incrementally release "add-on packs" with more cards. I understand that it's impossible to change a smart contract after it's deployed, so, regarding the release of extra cards, is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ERC721 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) has no specifications as to how your contract creates or destroys tokens. This means you're free to implement your own functions which mint and burn tokens as you see fit.

The only requirement is that when creating a new token, you emit the `Transfer` event with the `from` address being `0x0`, and when destroying a token you emit the same event but with the `to` address being `0x0`.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can call the mint() function at any time to create more tokens. Typically, it's used with the onlyOwner() modifier so that only the contract owner can mint new tokens.